# Using regex in R to find strings as whole words (but not strings as part of words)

Tags: r, regex

I'm searching for the right regular expression. The following

```
t1 = c("IGF2, IGF2AS, INS, TH", "TH", "THZH", "ZGTH")
grep("TH",t1, value=T)
```

returns all elements of `t1`, but only the first and second are correct. I just want entries with word/phrase `TH` returned?

Comment: Despite there being two answers already, you should specify what you mean by 'words' as in your title. What about `TH2` or `TH_TH`?

Comment: @NickSabbe an excellent point and what I was struggling with. For the future reader who comes across, https://stackoverflow.com/a/40802619/7941188 shows how to do it with other boundaries

Answer (score 54):

You need to add [word boundary anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (`\b`) around your search strings so only entire words will be matched (i. e. words surrounded by non-word characters or start/end of string, where "word character" means `\w`, i.e. alphanumeric character).

Try

```
grep("\\bTH\\b",t3, value=T)
```

Comment: in R, it should be \\b

Answer (score 24):

You can use `\<` and `\>` in a regexp to match at the beginning/end of the word.

`grep ("\\<TH\\>", t1)` etc.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker was faster :) I wonder, if these two regexps differ?

Comment: Yours is more explicit, although in this case, they are functionally identical.