# How to use grep()/gsub() to find exact match

Tags: r, regex, word-boundary

```
string = c("apple", "apples", "applez")
grep("apple", string)
```

This would give me the index for all three elements in `string`. But I want an exact match on the word "apple" (i.e I just want `grep()` to return index 1).

Comment: For exact matches, consider using `==` or `match`.

Comment: What about for gsub instead of grep?

Comment: Combining `any` and `==` is better option if you don't need `grep` arguments such as `ignore.case = true` or `value = true`

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/7227976/680068

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Use word boundary `\b` which matches a between a word and non-word character,

```
string = c("apple", "apples", "applez")
grep("\\bapple\\b", string)
[1] 1
```

**OR**

Use anchors. `^` Asserts that we are at the start. `$` Asserts that we are at the end.

```
grep("^apple$", string)
[1] 1
```

You could store the regex inside a variable and then use it like below.

```
pat <- "\\bapple\\b"
grep(pat, string)
[1] 1
pat <- "^apple$"
grep(pat, string)
[1] 1
```

Update:

```
paste("^",pat,"$", sep="")
[1] "^apple$"
string
[1] "apple"   "apple:s" "applez" 
pat
[1] "apple"
grep(paste("^",pat,"$", sep=""), string)
[1] 1
```

Comment: `paste0("^",pat,"$")` saves a few characters of typing over `paste`. No need for `sep=""`

Answer (score 45):

For exact matching, it makes the most sense to use `==`. Additionally, this will be faster than `grep()`, and is obviously much easier.

```
which(string == "apple")
# [1] 1
```

Comment: Since `which(string %in% "apple")` also works and you mention speed, I would like to know if `==` is faster than `%in%`?