# Understanding grep with fixed = T in R

Tags: r

I checked different posts on this, but still couldn't figure out why this is not working:

```
c=c("HI","NO","YESS")
grep("YES",c,fixed=T)
[1] 3
```

If I am using `fixed = T`, why I am still getting a results when there is no exact match for "YES". I want only exact matches like when I use `grep -w` in bash.

Comment: For exact matches simply don't use regex. Just use `==` or `%in%`. In your case there was and exact match of "YES" and everything else was ignored. `fixed = TRUE` just tells `grep` there is no regular expression in the `pattern`.

Comment: `fixed=TRUE` means that the `pattern` shouldn't be considered a `regex`, but just as it is. Your vector contains the substring `YES` and so the match. It doesn't mean that the string must be **exactly** equal to the pattern, but it suffices that it **contains** the pattern.

Comment: Oh I see. Is there a way to tell R to find the exact match? An equivalent of `grep -w`?

Comment: Oh sure. Just `which(c=="YES")`.

Answer (score 5):

This just means that you're matching a string rather than a regular expression, but the string can still be a substring. If you want to match exact cases only, how about

```
> x=c("HI","NO","YESS") #better not to name variables after common functions
> grep("^YES$",x,fixed=F) 
integer(0)
```

**Edit** per @nicola: This works b/c `^` means beginning and `$` end of string, so `^xxxx$` forces the entire string to match `xxxx`.

Comment: No need of `regex` based functions (like `grep`). A simple `which(c=="YES")` is to be preferred in this case.

Comment: Agree; post as answer. But OP is using `grep`, titled question "understanding grep," and might like to know more about how it works and how to modify it for more cases.

Comment: That was already expressed in the comments. I agree that your post can be useful; I'd add a brief explanation of why it works (i.e. explain what `^` and `$` do).

Answer (score 0):

Best solution seems to be using `\b` as a word boundary, like `grep("\\bYES\\b",x)`. In other cases you have limitations, e. g. if you had `c=c("HI","NO","YES S")` or `c=c("HI","NO","YES,S")`, `^YES$` or `which(c=="YES")` would not help you to find "YES" in those strings.

Found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26813671/14590183