# Search for the nearest string

Tags: r

A table with many rows, but for simplicity of the problem...

```
> df <- data.frame(V1=c("imp: abc","apple","","imp: xyz","","lemon","ball","bell"),
                 V2=c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"),
                 V3=c("NA","7","NA","2,8","NA","NA","NA","NA"))

      V1               V2              V3
1  imp: abc             1              NA
2  apple                2              7
3                       3              NA
4  imp: xyz             4              2,8
5                       5              NA
6  lemon                6              NA
7  ball                 7              NA
8  bell                 8              NA
```

So what I am trying to achieve is search for the nearest string "imp:" in V1 based on V3 and V2. For example, V3 is 7, then go to row 7 and from there search for the nearest "imp:" in V1 which is nothing but imp: xyz present in 4 th row.

If there are multiple numbers in V3, for example V3 is 2, 8 then first go to row 2 and from there search for the nearest "imp:" in V1 which is nothing but imp: abc present in 1st row and again go to row 8 and from there search for the nearest "imp:" in V1 which is nothing but imp: xyz present in 4 th row.

Here's what output looks like:

```
      V1               V2              V3          V4
1  imp: abc             1              NA
2  apple                2              7           imp: xyz 
3                       3              NA
4  imp: xyz             4              2,8         imp: abc, imp: xyz
5                       5              NA
6  lemon                6              NA
7  ball                 7              NA
8  bell                 8              NA
```

**NOTE:** Search has to be upwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one solution, although it's not all that fast- if you have many rows it might not be the best way to go. Using your `df` as above, first make sure your NA values are not strings, and add an NA-filled column V4:

```
df$V3[df$V3 == "NA"] <- NA
df$V4 <- NA
```

Parse the index values from V3 into individual numerical values:

```
keys <- strsplit(as.character(df$V3), ",")

keysn <- lapply(keysn, as.numeric)
```

**Edit:** Forgot these two lines to assign the rownames from the original df to the list of lists. Add these in and it should work- if not, let me know again!

```
names(keysn) <- rownames(df)

keysn <- keysn[!is.na(keysn)]
```

Then, use `lapply` to iterate over the list of lists of numerical indices, and take the V1 value of the max row number from row 1 up to the current index. For multi values (eg, `2,8`), paste those values together before returning.

```
lx<-lapply(keysn, function(x){
  xout <-lapply(x, function(y){
    rn <- unlist(as.numeric(row.names(df[1:y,])))
    matchvals <- rn[which(grepl("imp", as.character(df$V1)))]
    matchvals <- matchvals[which(!is.na(matchvals))]
    maxmatch <- max(matchvals)
    out_text <- as.character(df$V1[maxmatch])
  })
  xout <- paste(xout, collapse = ", ")
  return(unlist(as.character(xout)))
})

> lx
$`2`
[1] "imp: xyz"

$`4`
[1] "imp: abc, imp: xyz"
```

Finally, use the names of the list items to update the V4 column with the appropriate values.

```
df$V4[as.numeric(names(lx))] = lx

> df
        V1 V2   V3                 V4
1 imp: abc  1 <NA>                 NA
2    apple  2    7           imp: xyz
3           3 <NA>                 NA
4 imp: xyz  4  2,8 imp: abc, imp: xyz
5           5 <NA>                 NA
6    lemon  6 <NA>                 NA
7     ball  7 <NA>                 NA
8     bell  8 <NA>                 NA
```

Comment: it gives me this error " Error in 1:y : NA/NaN argument "

Comment: With your full data set or with the example one?

Comment: example one same as above

Comment: Sorry, I dropped a few lines somehow. Edited answer to include those, please let me know if it still doesn't work!

Comment: If I want the grep function to search for strings exactly, what can I do? for example, string = c("apple", "apples", "applez")                        
  grep("apple", string) would return all three, but just wanted one with exactly "apple".                                                                                                                            I know this is possible by using "word boundary \b", it works in the **string ** example but, in our case, what we can do ?

Comment: Were you looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26813667/how-to-use-grep-to-find-exact-match) for the "apples" "applez" example? The anchors given there by Avinash Raj should work: for example, change `"imp"` in the answer above to `"^imp: abc&"` to only search for exact matches to "imp: abc", down to the spaces. What was the string you were looking to match?

Comment: lapply(V4, function(x) df$V2[grep(x,df$V1, fixed = TRUE)]))              I have a line as shown above, So I cannot really use "^x&", right?                  In such cases how can I achieve the same?

Comment: I don't know that I understand- I don't know what V4 is in this case. But, if you are iterating over a list of strings, you could use the anchor by using `paste` as in the other answer ([linked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26813667/how-to-use-grep-to-find-exact-match)). You may want to ask a new question or edit your existing one for clarity (and it's much easier to answer to that).