# How to grep exact matches using a vector in R?

Tags: r

I have a large data frame where I want to extract rows based on a column value. My problem is that grep will take all instances of the value (e.g. will take "11" if I wanted to grep "1"). How do I get exact matches? Example below simply illustrates my issue. I only want to grep the "metm1" row but it is grepping all rows even though they are not exact matches.

```
## make data

df1 <- data.frame(matrix(, nrow=4, ncol=2))
colnames(df1) <- c("met", "dt1")
df1$met <- c("metm11", "metm1", "metm1", "metm12")
df1$dt1 <- c("0.666", "0.777", "0.99", "0.01")

# make list for grep

mets <- "metm1"

# grep

new_df <- as.data.frame(df1[grep(paste(mets, collapse = "|"), df1$met), ])
```

Comment: Relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26813667/how-to-use-grep-gsub-to-find-exact-match

Comment: Don't use `grep`. just use an exact match with `%in%`: `df1[df1$met %in% mets, ]`

Answer (score 1):

You may place `^` and `$` anchors around the search term to force an exact match:

```r
regex <- paste0("^(?:", paste(mets, collapse = "|"), ")$")
new_df <- as.data.frame(df1[grep(regex, df1$met, fixed=TRUE), ])
```

For reference, the regex pattern being used here in:

```regex
^(?:metm1)$
^(?:metm1|metm2|metm3)$   <-- for multiple terms
```

Comment: Is there any advantage to using `grep` in this case rather than a more direct `%in%` for exact matches?

Comment: @MrFlick That was in the back of my mind when I posted.  You're right, the OP should probably use `%in%` for semantic purposes.  In any case, I have updated my answer to use `fixed=TRUE`, which should improve performance by largely turning off the regex engine (which doesn't need to be fully used).

Answer (score 1):

You can use simply `==` to make exact match.

```
df1[df1$met == mets,]
#    met   dt1
#2 metm1 0.777
#3 metm1  0.99
```

In case `mets` is more than one element long use `%in%` as already pointed out in the comments by @MrFlick.

```
df1[df1$met %in% mets,]
#    met   dt1
#2 metm1 0.777
#3 metm1  0.99
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is by using boundary anchors `\\b`:

```
df1[grep(paste0("\\b(", paste0(mets, collapse = "|"),")\\b"), df1$met), ]
    met   dt1
2 metm1 0.777
3 metm1  0.99
```

Using `dplyr` you'd `filter` with `grepl`, which returns `TRUE` and `FALSE` whereas `grep` returns indices of matches:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  filter(grepl(paste0("\\b(", paste0(mets, collapse = "|"),")\\b"), met))
```