# How to remove rows by condition in R?

Tags: r, subset

I'm new to R and I was wondering if there is an opposite code of 'which' in R?

So e.g. when I run the code below, then it keeps all the data between 10 and 50 and removes everything else. The code below works for me, there is no problem there.

```
data <- data[which(data$age>10 & data$age<50),]
```

But I want to know if there is a code that can do the opposite? Meaning --> I want to remove specific rows from the data, so instead of having a code that says what to keep I want a code that indicates what to remove. If that makes sense?
I want to remove a specific row by condition.

I have tried with the subset code, but I can't get it to work.
The below code is the code I tried that didn't work

```
data2 <- subset(data1, data1$gender=='male')
```

So gender is a column, with females and males. And I want a code to remove the males only.

Comment: Use `-`, e.g `data[-which(data$age>10 & data$age<50),]`

Comment: That worked!! :D Thank you so much. 
I did this data2 <- data1[-which(data1$gender=='male'),]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although this should be a comment, since you said you are new to R let me take a bit more space to explain this in a non-technical way as it is clear there is some confusion.

First, when you index in R using brackets (ie, `df[x,y]`), the `x` part (before the comma) looks at rows, and the `y` part looks at columns. Your question title asks about removing columns, but your question asks about removing rows. So I will go through both.

Say you have these data (note some have missing (`NA`) values):

```
set.seed(123)
n <- 10
df <- data.frame(Age = sample(c(1:100, NA), n, replace = TRUE),
                 Gender = sample(c("Male", "Female", NA), n, replace = TRUE),
                 Cofactor = rep(LETTERS, length.out = n),
                 Cofactor2 = sample(c("Yes", "No", "Maybe", NA), n, replace = TRUE),
                 Cofactor3 = runif(n))

#    Age Gender Cofactor Cofactor2  Cofactor3
# 1   31 Female        A       Yes 0.02461368
# 2   79   Male        B     Maybe 0.47779597
# 3   51 Female        C      <NA> 0.75845954
# 4   14   <NA>        D        No 0.21640794
# 5   67   Male        E     Maybe 0.31818101
# 6   42   <NA>        F        No 0.23162579
# 7   50   <NA>        G       Yes 0.14280002
# 8   43   Male        H        No 0.41454634
# 9   NA   Male        I     Maybe 0.41372433
# 10  14   Male        J      <NA> 0.36884545
```

#### Dropping **Rows**

You can index rows by row position using numbers - i.e. if you want to keep or drop the first three rows:

```
# keep 
df[1:3, ]

# drop
df[-c(1:3),]
```

Notice commands are in the `x` indexing position (left of the comma). If you wanted to drop the observations (rows) that were male, you could do it several ways. For instance:

```
df[!(df$Gender %in% "Male"),]

# or using `which()`
df[-(which(df$Gender %in% "Male")),]

#   Age Gender Cofactor1  Cofactor2
# 1  31 Female       Yes 0.02461368
# 3  51 Female      <NA> 0.75845954
# 4  14   <NA>        No 0.21640794
# 6  42   <NA>        No 0.23162579
# 7  50   <NA>       Yes 0.14280002
```

The `!` means "not" - so this reads, "select rows that are *not* male" - *including* `NA` values.

If you did this:

```
df[df$Gender %in% "Female",]

# or 
df[which(df$Gender %in% "Female"),]

#   Age Gender Cofactor1  Cofactor2
# 1  31 Female       Yes 0.02461368
# 3  51 Female      <NA> 0.75845954
```

That would read "include all where gender is female" - notice `NA` != female so they are not included.

Similarly, if you wanted to include both "yes" and "maybe" in `Cofactor1`:

```
df[df$Cofactor1 %in% c("Yes", "Maybe"),]

#   Age Gender Cofactor1  Cofactor2
# 1  31 Female       Yes 0.02461368
# 2  79   Male     Maybe 0.47779597
# 5  67   Male     Maybe 0.31818101
# 7  50   <NA>       Yes 0.14280002
# 9  NA   Male     Maybe 0.41372433
```

Note that I am using `%in%`, not `==`, this is because of [vector recycling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15358006/what-is-the-difference-between-in-and) - see what happens when I use `==` (hint, it gives unwanted results):

```
df[df$Cofactor1 == c("Yes", "Maybe"),]

#     Age Gender Cofactor1  Cofactor2
#1     31 Female       Yes 0.02461368
#2     79   Male     Maybe 0.47779597
#NA    NA   <NA>      <NA>         NA
#7     50   <NA>       Yes 0.14280002
#NA.1  NA   <NA>      <NA>         NA
```

The correct way to use `==` is much more verbose (`df[(df$Cofactor1 == "Yes"| df$Cofactor1 == "Maybe") & !is.na(df$Cofactor1),]` so using `%in%` is a good option here.

#### Keeping/Dropping **Columns**

Indexing columns is on the `y` position of indexing (to the right of the comma). If your data have a large number of unneeded columns, you can simply choose the ones you want to keep by indexing by name (or column number:

```
df[,c("Age", "Gender")]

# or df[, 1:2]

#    Age Gender
# 1   31 Female
# 2   79   Male
# 3   51 Female
# 4   14   <NA>
# 5   67   Male
# 6   42   <NA>
# 7   50   <NA>
# 8   43   Male
# 9   NA   Male
# 10  14   Male
```

But you can **only** drop columns by number (I know, quirky) - so you **cant** drop by `df[,-c("Age", "Gender")]` but you can drop by `df[,-c(1:2)]`

In my work it is preferred to drop by name since columns get shifted around a bit - so with names I know exactly what I am dropping. One workaround I use is to use `grep` with `names(df)` to identify the positions of the columns that I want to drop.

This is a little tricky so be careful. If I want to drop *all* columns that start with "Cofactor" in the name:

```
dropcols <- grep("Cofactor", names(df))

# or to ignore case
# grep("Cofactor", names(df), ignore.case = TRUE)
# [1] 3 4 5
```

If I **only** wanted to drop `Cofactor` but keep `Cofactor1` and `Cofactor2`, I could use `\\b` to put a [word boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26813667/how-to-use-grep-gsub-to-find-exact-match) on it:

```
dropcols <- grep("\\bCofactor\\b", names(df))
[1] 3
```

So to drop the columns, you can simply index like so:

```
dropcols <- grep("Cofactor", names(df))
df[, -dropcols]

#    Age Gender
# 1   31 Female
# 2   79   Male
# 3   51 Female
# 4   14   <NA>
# 5   67   Male
# 6   42   <NA>
# 7   50   <NA>
# 8   43   Male
# 9   NA   Male
# 10  14   Male
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function filter in the library dplyr:
data2<- filter(data1, gender!="Male")