# How to find string matches between two unequal sized vectors in R?

Tags: r, string, variables, dplyr

I have two vectors with strings as follows:

```
x <- c("Zimbabwe (Rhodesia)", "India", "Equatorial Guinea", "United States")

y <- c("Zimbabwe", "India", "Guinea")
```

I want to obtain a vector that contains those strings that do not **exactly** match between `x` and `y`. The result would ideally be:

```
"Zimbabwe (Rhodesia)" "Zimbabwe" "Equatorial Guinea" "Guinea" "United States"
```

I am trying to consolidate a few concepts here -
I know I can use `grep(paste(y, collapse = "|")` to get a partial match for a vector, and [anchors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26813667/how-to-use-grep-gsub-to-find-exact-match) to find an exact match for one given string. But how to integrate them?

How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option would be to use set operations, i.e. using the set difference of the union and the intersection:

```r
x <- c("Zimbabwe (Rhodesia)", "India", "Equatorial Guinea", "United States")

y <- c("Zimbabwe", "India", "Guinea")

setdiff(union(x, y), intersect(x, y))
#> [1] "Zimbabwe (Rhodesia)" "Equatorial Guinea"   "United States"      
#> [4] "Zimbabwe"            "Guinea"
```

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility, which might be a bit more intuitive:

```r
x = c("Zimbabwe (Rhodesia)", "India", "Equatorial Guinea", "United States")
y = c("Zimbabwe", "India", "Guinea")
c(x[!(x %in% y)], y[!(y %in% x)])
#> [1] "Zimbabwe (Rhodesia)" "Equatorial Guinea"   "United States"      
#> [4] "Zimbabwe"            "Guinea"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

In "alphabetically decreasing" order:

```r
> c(x[!(x %in% y)], y[!(y %in% x)]) |> 
+   { \(.) .[order(., decreasing = TRUE)] }()
[1] "Zimbabwe (Rhodesia)" "Zimbabwe"            "United States"       "Guinea"             
[5] "Equatorial Guinea"
```

Answer (score 1):

you could concatenate and drop duplicated ones:

```
c(x,y)[!c(x,y) %in% intersect(x,y)]

[1] "Zimbabwe (Rhodesia)" "Equatorial Guinea"   "United States"       "Zimbabwe"            "Guinea"
```