# Counting occurence of a word in a text file using R

Tags: r, text, find-occurrences

I try to create  a function which returns the number of occurence of a word in a text file.
For this, I create a List which contains all the words of a text. (a, c,, c , d, e, f are here in the example words)

```
[[1]]

 [1] a  

 [2] f 

 [3] e       

 [4] a 

[[2]] 

 [1] f 

 [2] f

 [3] e
```

I create a table to stock for each word it number of occurence value

```
table(unlist(list))

  a b c d e

  3 3 2 1 1
```

My question now is how can I extract the value of occurence of a word in parameter.
The function will have this structure

```
GetOccurence <- function(word, table)
{
   return(occurence)
}
```

Any idea please to help me, Thanks in advance

Comment: The subject of text mining with use of **R** is rather well-described, if you want to consider having a look at [this article](https://deltadna.com/blog/text-mining-in-r-for-term-frequency/) you can find basic approach to undertake frequency analysis on a text file.

Comment: `tm` package will be of help here

Comment: You can index a table, as the levels become names. Thus `table(mtcars$cyl)['6']` returns the number of 6-cylindered cars in `mtcars`. If that's your question; it's a little ambiguous.

Comment: Ok thank you, but my question if wor example i want to look for the frequency of "hello", how can I do to pass "hello" in parameter to extract its frequency?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the question with respect to your function you could take the following approach.

## Data preparation

*For the sake of reproducibility, I used publicly-available data and cleaned it a little.*

```
library(tm)
data(acq)

# Basic cleaning
acq <- tm_map(acq, removePunctuation)  
acq <- tm_map(acq, removeNumbers)     
acq <- tm_map(acq, tolower)     
acq <- tm_map(acq, removeWords, stopwords("english"))  
acq <- tm_map(acq, stripWhitespace)   
acq <- tm_map(acq, PlainTextDocument) 

# Split list into words
wrds <- strsplit(paste(unlist(acq), collapse = " "), ' ')[[1]]
# Table
tblWrds <- table(wrds)
```

---

## Function

```
GetOccurence <- function(word, table) {
    occurence <- as.data.frame(table)
    occurence <- occurence[grep(word, occurence[,1]), ]
    return(occurence)
}
```

### Modified *(full words only)*

*This function will match the **full** words only, the solution below capitalises on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7227999/1655567).*

```
GetOccurence <- function(word, table) {
    occurence <- as.data.frame(table)
    word <- paste0("\\b", word, "\\b")
    occurence <- occurence[grep(word, occurence[,1]), ]
    return(occurence)
}
```

Comment: Thank you Konard your example helps me a lot !! Cheers$

Comment: @Fish No problem at all, just a side note that I left the `data.frame` as *occurrence* but if you want to get your figure it will be in the second column `occurence[,2]` just whatever is more convenient.