# Grep in R to find words with custom "extended" boundaries

Tags: r, regex

I'm looking for a regular expression to grep whole words, *including* words separated by digits or underscore. `\\b` considers digits and underscore as parts of words, not as boundaries.

For example, I'd like to catch MOUSE in "DOG MOUSE CAT", in "DOG MOUSE:CAT" but also in "DOG_MOUSE9CAT" and at the end or the beginning of an expression, as in "MOUSE9CAT" and "DOG_MOUSE". Basically, the boundary I'm looking for is any non-uppercase-alpha character plus beginning and end of line/expression (maybe missing some other cases caught by `\\b` here).

I've tried:

```
"[[0-9_]\\b]MOUSE[[0-9_]\\b]"
"[[0-9_]|\\b]MOUSE[[0-9_]|\\b]"
"[$|[^A-Z]]MOUSE[^|[^A-Z]]"
"[?<=^|[^A-Z]]MOUSE[?=$|[^A-Z]]"
```

None of them work.

I'm actually looking for several words (based on a long vector of values), so the final result should look something like

```
grep(paste("\\b", paste(searchwords, collapse = "\\b|\\b"), "\\b"), targettext)
```

(with a different delimiter because `\\b` is too restrictive for me).

(This is a similar question to the one asked by user Nick Sabbe in a comment here: [Using grep in R to find strings as whole words (but not strings as part of words)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227976/using-grep-in-r-to-find-strings-as-whole-words-but-not-strings-as-part-of-words))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use PCRE regex with lookarounds:

```
grep("(?<![A-Z])MOUSE(?![A-Z])", targettext, perl=TRUE)
```

See the [regex demo](http://(?%3C![A-Z])MOUSE(?![A-Z]))

The `(?<![A-Z])` negative lookbehind will fail the match if the word is preceded with an uppercase ASCII letter and the negative lookahead `(?![A-Z])` will fail the match if the word is followed with an uppercase ASCII letter.

To apply the lookarounds to all the alternatives you have, use an outer grouping `(?:...|...)`.

See the [R online demo](https://ideone.com/cdOUse):

```
> targettext <- c("DOG MOUSE CAT","DOG MOUSE:CAT","DOG_MOUSE9CAT","MOUSE9CAT","DOG_MOUSE")
> searchwords <- c("MOUSE","FROG")
> grep(paste0("(?<![A-Z])(?:", paste(searchwords, collapse = "|"), ")(?![A-Z])"), targettext, perl=TRUE)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Fantastic! thank you so much. This actually returns the same result as \\b with my data (which is very long), but my confidence level has increased thanks to you :)

Comment: The `\b` meaning is context dependent, while the lookarounds provide a way to use unambiguous and customizable boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is using `rflashtext` library

Build a `KeywordProcessor` object using the next parameters:

- keys: The words you want to search. In this case `c("DOG", "MOUSE", "CAT")`
- chars: The characters used to validate if a word continue, opposite to the boundary. In your case uppercase letters `paste(LETTERS, collapse = "")`

Use the function `find_keys` to search the `keys` on each sentence. Set `span_info` as `FALSE` to only retrieve the words, for retrieving the words and the position of the matches use `TRUE`.

To get a the same output as `grep` use `which` combined with `lengths` and `unlist`

```
library(rflashtext)

processor <- KeywordProcessor$new(keys = c("DOG", "MOUSE", "CAT"),
                                  chars = paste(LETTERS, collapse = ""))

found <- processor$find_keys(sentences = c("DOG MOUSE CAT", "DOG MOUSE:CAT",
                                           "DOG_MOUSE9CAT", "MOUSE9CAT",
                                           "DOG_MOUSE"), 
                             span_info = FALSE)

found

[[1]]
[[1]]$word
[1] "DOG"   "MOUSE" "CAT"  


[[2]]
[[2]]$word
[1] "DOG"   "MOUSE" "CAT"  


[[3]]
[[3]]$word
[1] "DOG"   "MOUSE" "CAT"  


[[4]]
[[4]]$word
[1] "MOUSE" "CAT"  


[[5]]
[[5]]$word
[1] "DOG"   "MOUSE"

which(lengths(unlist(found, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE)) > 0)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```