# How to replace an exact string using stringr functions?

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I'm trying to replace exact strings in a column using `stringr` functions.

The dataset I try it on is this:

```
data <- data.frame(
  column = c("Value", "Values", "Value", "Values")
)

data

  column
1 Value
2 Values
3 Value
4 Values
```

I want to replace "Value" with "Values". I tried `str_replace(data$column, "Value", "Values")`, but this creates the following unwanted replacements:

```
[1] "Values"  "Valuess" "Values"  "Valuess"
```

I'd like the output to be:

```
[1] "Values"  "Values" "Values"  "Values"
```

Comment: try `str_replace(data$column, "Value\\b", "Values")` and have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227976/using-grep-in-r-to-find-strings-as-whole-words-but-not-strings-as-part-of-words).

Comment: as suggested by @Ravinder. Please use `sub()` for this task. Stay `base::` where you can.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit why one should choose base where one can?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are a few possibilities using regular expressions:

```
x <- c("value", "values")
str_replace(x, "value$", "values") #method 1
str_replace(x, "value\\b", "values") #method 2
str_replace(x, "value(?!s)", "values") #method 3
```

all of the above return the same

```
[1] "values" "values"
```

A short explanation: the first method looks for 'value' at the end of a string. The symbol `$` matches the end of the string.

The second method looks for 'value' followed by a word boundary.

The third method looks for 'value' followed by anything but the symbol 's'.

You can find a helpful cheat sheet about stringr and regular expressions 
[here](https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/raw/master/strings.pdf).
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any suggested comprehensive resources to learn more about regular expressions in stringr context?

Comment: I personally struggled a lot to understand regular expressions. What helped me in the end was the second page of the cheat sheet I posted in the answer plus a couple of hours experimenting with the examples they provide there.

Comment: @MetaPhilosopher regex101.com

Comment: Use `^value$` for start and end of string.

Answer (score 2):

Just a simple string comparison should do the trick.

```
data[data$col == "Value","col"] = "Values"
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following:

```
sub("Value[a-z]+","Values",data$column)
```

Output will be as follows.

```
sub("Value[a-z]+","Values",data$column,perl = TRUE)
[1] "Values" "Values" "Values" "Values"
```

***Explanation:*** Following is only for explanation purposes.

```
sub(             ##using sub function of R whose method is: sub(regex_to_match_in_current_value,new_value_which_should_be_there_after_match,variable)
"Value[a-z]+",   ##mentioning Value string with [a-z]+ alphabets till their regular sequences.
"Value",         ##Substitute above match of strings with only string Value here.
data$column)     ##Mentioning data frame data with its column.
```

Where sample data is from:

```
data <- data.frame(
  column = c("Value", "Values", "Value", "Values")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

data$column <- ifelse(data$column=='Value','Values','Values')